# R shiny can show chinese on windows but not on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, character, shiny

I am confused why R shiny are able to show chinese character variables and values ,and are also able to do the logistic regression on those character value in windows platform but when i upload it to the virtual machine under ubuntu ,
the chorme console will show "Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string at '�״̬'"
any one know how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is in shiny you could try forcing the page encoding in shiny to utf-8 by setting the meta charset attribute like:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML("
      $('html > head').append('<meta charset="UTF-8"/>');
      "))
  ),
  # Application title
  titlePanel("তথ্যসংগ্রহ"),
  sidebarPanel(
  ),
  mainPanel()
))
```

Or you could set the R encoding (can be other than utf-8 too):

```
options(encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

Or finally you could try to call Sys.setlocale

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE",[your locale])
```

Comment: thanks, finally I convert this file from GBK to UTF8 , before Read it into R , and it was resolved